# Magento2: Invalid block type

Tags: magento2, layout, static-block

I am adding static block in footer and getting this error.

**Invalid block type**. where is my mistake.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">  
    <block type="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footerslinks">
       <arguments>
         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footers_links</argument>
       </arguments>
    </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: anything in the logs? maybe it fails to create the instance for some reason https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php#L258

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute is called `class`, not `type`

Comment: I am still obsessed with m1 :D :D

Comment: can you tell me why it is rendering html show as it is?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Did you enter HTML with the WYSIWYG editor enabled?